# How to find the minimum of $5^x-x^5$ on $x\in(-2,1)$

Tags: calculus

> Determine minimum value of the function $f(x) = 5^x - x^5$ on the interval $-2 < x < 1$

When I differentiate, I get $f’(x)= 5^x \ln 5 - 5x^4$. Then, I’m stuck.

Comment: I meant minimum value in the question and the answer is 0.458

Comment: You can search about Lambert's $W$ function to solve that equation, or you can approximate the answer, try using Newton's method, the good thing is that the derivative isn't that long and you can calculate a few terms by hand, besides, you know the answer is approximately $1$, so that seems like a good starting point, and Newton's method improves quadratically, so I'm sure you'll get a few digits very quick.

Comment: An exact answer can be given by using the Lambert W function. Is that acceptable to you? The answer is in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+5%5Ex*ln(5)-5*x%5E4%3D0) and we could show how to derive that if you ask. Also, your "answer" is wrong--the correct answer is closer to −0.59327. Your "answer" is closer to the inflection point, not the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, we want to solve the equation

$$5^x\log5=5x^4$$

We can rewrite this as

$$5^x=\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}x}{(\log5)^{1/4}}\right)^4$$

Making the substitution $u=\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}x}{(\log5)^{1/4}}=c_0x$ we get an equation of the form

$$u^4=5^{u/c_0}$$
$$u^4= e^{uc_1\log5}$$
$$u^4=e^{c_2u}$$

With $c_1=1/c_0$ and $c_2=c_1\log5$. And so we get an equation of the form $x^n=e^{-ax}$ which is covered in Example 4 of the section "Solutions to equations" in [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 0):

$5^x \ln(5) - 5x^4 = 0 \iff x(5^{-1/4})^{x} = \pm(\frac{\ln 5}{5})^{1/4} $ or $x(5^{-1/4})^{x} = \pm i(\frac{\ln 5}{5})^{1/4}$.

We now have the equation in the form $x a^x = z$, the solution to which is $x = \frac{W(z \ln a)}{\ln a}$. Plugging each value of z into this will give us our solutions.

E.g. one solution is $ x = \frac{W(\frac{\ln5}{5})^{1/4} \ln (5^{-1/4}))}{\ln (5^{-1/4})}$. You can use wolfram alpha to evaluate the $W$ function.

Answer (score 0):

The function $5^x \ln 5 -5x^4$ 
The image of 0 is positive the image of -2 is negative and of 1 is positive our zero is between -2,0 lets see -1 
It going to be $\frac{\ln  5}{5}-5$ which is negative hence the zero is between $-0.5$ and $0$ so the function is decreasing sine the derivative sign is negative until we reach a certain number between $-0.5$ and $0$ then it is going up so -2 is going to be the maximum. You can try graphing it. Or you could say the following $5^x$ is increasing function on the interval , $\frac{1}{25}$ and the highest is $5$ while $-x^5$ is decreasing begin with $32$ and ends with $1$ and we need to maximize the addition 
$0.04$ to $5$ 
$32$ to $1$ 
I know this argument fails in many cases we need to consider also that $-x^5$ decreasing faster the derivative $-5x^4$ , $5^x \ln 5$ is increasing slower in that interval.